# What's the right way to modify the params passed to controller in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, factory-bot

In our Rails 3.1.0 app, we need to modify params passed to rfq controller in create and update. For example, we want to record the current user id under input_by_id. What we did was:

```
  @rfq.input_by_id = session[:user_id]
```

It worked as expected. Also when need_report field is false, then report_language field should be nil. We decide to add the following line in rfq controller to make sure the nil is passed to report_language when need_report is false:

```
  @rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report]
```

However this addition causes the rspec case failure (in create/update of the controller) because of the data validation failure. However when we fire up the app, it behaves fine without saving the report_language when need_report is false. I am wondering if the line above is not the right way to use params[:need_report] for @rfq updating.

Thanks so much.

UPDATE:

Controller code:

```
  def create
    if has_create_right?
      @rfq = Rfq.new(params[:rfq], :as => :roles_new )
      @rfq.input_by_id = session[:user_id]
      #save sales_id selected
      if sales? && member? && !team_lead?
        @rfq.sales_id = session[:user_id]        
      end
      #view page may carry the hidden report language even if need_report == false
      @rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report]
      #save into join table rfqs_standards
      params[:rfq][:standard_ids].each do |sid|  
        @rfq.standards << Standard.find(sid.to_i) if !sid.nil? && sid.to_i > 0 
      end unless params[:rfq][:standard_ids].nil?
      #save into join table rfqs_test_items
      params[:rfq][:test_item_ids].each do |tid|
        @rfq.test_items << TestItem.find(tid.to_i) if !tid.nil? && tid.to_i > 0 
      end unless params[:rfq][:test_item_ids].nil?
      if @rfq.save!
        redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=RFQ saved!")
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "RFQ not saved!"
        render 'new'
      end
    else
       redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=No rights!") 
    end
  end
```

Test case failed after addition of `@rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report]`

```
   it "should be successful for corp head" do
      session[:corp_head] = true
      session[:user_id] = 1
      s = Factory(:standard)
      rfq = Factory.attributes_for(:rfq, :need_report => true, :report_language => 'EN')
      rfq[:standard_ids] = [s.id] # attach standard_id's to mimic the POST'ed form data
      get 'create', :rfq => rfq
      #response.should redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=RFQ saved!")
      response.should render_template('new')
    end
```

Comment: How exactly is the RSpec test failing? "data validation failure" is a little too vague to help. Can you post the code of one of your tests, and the code from that controller method? If it works fine in a browser, it probably means that your test is broken.

Comment: `@rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report]` is the equivalent of saying set `@rfq.report_language` to `nil` if `params[:need_report]` is `nil` or `false` (which would happen if a request was made to the action without passing a value in for that parameter).  you say you don't understand how to use the `params` hash; what behavior are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Batkins, what you said about the line of code is my understanding. However this line of code causes failure in data validation asking for choosing a language. In our test, the need_report was set to true and report_language was set to 'EN' in Factory.attributes_for and this should pass the data validation. Also @rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:need_report] should not fire.  We don't know why the case failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem ist that you are simply not looking at the right value.

`get 'create', :rfq => rfq` will result in a params-hash like `{:rfq => {...}}`

so you need to `@rfq.report_language = nil unless params[:rfq][:need_report] == 'true'`

Comment: I tested with params[:rfq][:need_report] again. One more rspec case passed. However when firing up the app, the report_language was saved even with need_report == false. It seems that params[:rfq][:need_report] was not fired up when need_report==false as it should be. Based on my understanding, params[:need_report] should return the value for need_report.

Comment: that's because you get a string and not a boolean. if you look at the params in detail you will see `"need_report" => "false"`it's all strings!

Comment: phoet, you are correct! I did print out params[:rfq][:need_report] and params[:need_report]. params[:rfq][:need_report] prints out true or false. However params[:need_report] prints out nothing. I compared [:rfq][:prod_name] and [:prod_name] and the result is the same. Did test in create and update in controller. The conclusion is that the right way to retrieve from params is params[:controller_name][:field_name]. params[:field_name] is not the right way to retrieve data.